# From aws-cli, how to only upload new application version and not deploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

Currently, I'm trying to automate build and deploy process of ElasticBeanstalk.  Especially, I'm searching for a way to operate following process separately.

1. Upload certain Application Version from aws-cli.
2. Deploy using certain Application Version via Web Console.

Now 2 is relatively trivial; the Web Console UI tells me how to.

About 1, I currently cannot find how to achieve this; the closest command I've found is `eb deploy`, which can do ApplicationVersion upload but also is tied to (as the name suggest) deployment.

Now the main reason why I want to do this is because I'd like to setup the process 1 achieved by Aws CodeBuild.  If it was only uploading an ApplicationVersion, then all the configuration I'd need would be an appropriate IAM configuration.  If 2 is needed, then I'd also need the private Key for accessing the env's instance, so I need to manage private key on Aws CodeBuild procedure, which I think would be rather cumbersome and would like to avoid.

#### Question

- From CodeDeploy's command line interface, I'd like to upload an ApplicationVersion only and not deploy.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I realized that to do this, I need to use `aws` command instead of `eb` command.

What I needed was [`aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/create-application-version.html)